# How to change style to java google style on Intellij

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I'm trying to set the google style for java in Intellij but until now I didn't succeed.
My problem is after I imported the style I couldn't see any new error or warnings from what I had without the style.
Can someone help me to understand how I enable this style so I could see the changes..
I used this [Installing the google styleguide settings in intellij and eclipse](https://github.com/HPI-Information-Systems/Metanome/wiki/Installing-the-google-styleguide-settings-in-intellij-and-eclipse).
If it's make difference, I'm develop from android.

Comment: This style is for code formatting and is applied after Reformat Code (after selecting this style for editor in Settings | Editor | Code Style), why do you expect to see any new warnings or errors?

Comment: Because it supposed to tell me when I'm not using the right name for vars according to https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming and it doesn't do that...

Comment: Code style profile doesn't do that, it's done by the inspection profile. You have imported the code style profile and expect it to work as inspection profile?

Comment: I don't know what is an inspection profile.. Do you know what I need to do in order to get what I thought I get from the style profile?

Comment: I don't know if there exists a public inspections profile used at Google for IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Easier way：install google-java-format plugin in Intellij.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who interest, the steps are :
1. install CheckStyle plugin via IntelliJ.
2. go to Settings > Other settings > CheckStyle.
3. add this [file](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml) as rules file.
4. run CheckStyle.
Thanks you all. Hope it's helping.